# How to start using velocity

Tags: java, velocity

How do I start using velocity? Is there a place that helps me understand what do I need to install? which server? how to start? first steps?

I know how to install wamp (I have windows) and work a bit with PHP on aptana - so this is my general knowledge and I need to know the first steps to velocity (what type of server do I need? Will Aptana do the trick or do I need to install also eclipse?)

thanks,
Alon

Comment: To quote [their site](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html): _"The Velocity engine subproject contains the documentation to get started using the Velocity templating language and embedding Velocity into your own applications."_

Answer (score 3):

The "Getting Started" section in the [Velocity developer guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html) is the place to get started on the code side.

What type of *server* do you need? Are you going to use Velocity to create a web application using Velocity? You'll likely want [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) (or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), etc.) to get started, because there's a ton of documentation and tutorials.

Aptana *is* Eclipse, but you might be better off with a plain old Eclipse; Aptana is geared more towards framework-specific functionality (PHP, Rails, etc.) You should be able to add the Java ecosystem web stuff to it if it isn't already there; not sure how easy/difficult it would be.

Be aware that making a jump from PHP to Java web development is a big leap in terms of what you need to know, how apps are generally coded, the Java ecosystem (libraries in particular), etc.

Comment: hi Dave, I want to make the leap from PHP to Java web development - where is a good place to start? My short term goal is to know how to convert quiet simple PHP files into velocity. My bigger goal is to start learning java web development.

Comment: @Alon There's more to it than that, though; the bulk of work in a Java web app is done in Java, in a servlet or other framework, then dump data into the Velocity template. There's a tutorial [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/webapps.html) that's probably the leanest intro to one way to use Velocity in web apps.